# Is multiplayer wave objective preset or random?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

I just started playing multiplayer and I have been playing some Any Enemy, Any Location, Bronze challenge quick matches and I'm wondering if the wave objective type is preset or random?

As far as I can tell wave 3, 6 and 10 always have some objective; hack a system/upload data, Kill some important targets or enable/disable 4 devices, but is this objective preset depending on enemy and/or location? or is it random?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can almost certainly guarantee the objectives are spawned on a random basis.

I have tried my best to predict a pattern with the objective based waves and I have been unable to do so. There seems to be nothing that triggers specific objectives.

Answer (score 2):

I think they did what happened is Resistance 2 Co-op, they had presets of objectives but the order they were done in was random.

I can't guarantee this, but this is what i think.

Answer (score -1):

The game is set up for random waves, with only 3 waves garuntee to always be the same. Thats the first 2 for only killing monsters and the 11th wave for extraction.

I believe the deactivating/activating the 4 nodes is set to go off randomly on 3rd wave or higher, same with the stand in one are for 5 minutes to collect data. The kill your 4 targets wave I believe is set to be random from the 4th wave on.

But I think they have it in there that it wont do back to back waves of something. But could be: kill wave, target wave, kill wave, 4 node wave, kill wave, collect data, extraction. If you were unlucky, but gives you more coins. Because you get bonus coins based on how many seconds are left for each of those waves.